# Is there a way to limit the time zones available to the user to select from?

Tags: datetime

We have a Drupal 9 site that has a Smart Date field with Time Zones. However, the time zone selection list is huge. We want to limit it to the four main US times zones. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never personally used that module, but according to their release notes, since version [3.0.0-rc1](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_date/releases/3.0.0-rc1) this seems to be possible via the widget configuration:

> Another step towards a stable release for the 3.0.x branch. This release brings improved Gin and Claro compatibility, cleanup up a variety of UI/UX issues, and fixes for notices being logged in a variety of circumstances. Also included here is a substantial amount of coding standards cleanup, in some cases for code going back to the 2.x branch. **A new feature in the timezone widget is the ability to choose a subset of timezones to make available, so sites with a specific range of timezones to support can simplify the editor experience.** There is now also improved views handling for recurring events, including the ability to expose a filter to view events recurring at a specific frequency (daily, weekly, monthly, etc.).

I also see relevant code for that in the current release branch [src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/SmartDateTimezoneWidget.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/smart_date/-/blob/3.5.x/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/SmartDateTimezoneWidget.php#L29)

Comment: Oh my, yes, it was an option in the time zone widget config. It just wasn't clear that I had to select "custom'. Thank you!